# OpenSearch Indexes and Data streams

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch, amazon-opensearch

I have recently started to use OpenSearch and having a few newbie questions.

1. What is the difference between Index, Index Pattern and Index template? (Some examples would be really helpful to visualize and differentiate these terminologies).
2. I have seen some indexes with data streams and some without data streams. What exactly are data streams and why some indexes have them and the others do not.

Tried reading a few docs, watching a few youTube videos. But it's getting a little confusing as I do not have much hands on experience with OpenSearch.

Comment: was the answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

`(1)`

An `index` is a collection of JSON documents that you want to make searchable. To maximise your ability to search and analyse documents, you can define how documents and their fields are stored and indexed (i.e., [mappings](https://opensearch.org/docs/2.4/opensearch/mappings/) and settings).

An `index template` is a way to initialize with predefined mappings and settings new indices that match a given name pattern - e.g., any new index with a name starting with "java-" ([docs](https://opensearch.org/docs/2.4/opensearch/index-templates/)).

An `index pattern` is a concept associated with Dashboards, the OpenSearch UI. It provides Dashboards with a way to identify which indices you want to analyse, based on their name (again, usually based on prefixes).
[image: Index patterns]

`(2)`

Data streams are managed indices highly optimised for time-series and append-only data, typically, observability data. Under the hood, they work like any other index, but OpenSearch simplifies some management operations (e.g., rollovers) and stores in a more efficient way the continuous stream of data that characterises this scenario.

In general, if you have a continuous stream of data that is append-only and has a timestamp attached (e.g., logs, metrics, traces, ...), then data streams are advertised as the most efficient way to model this data in OpenSearch.